# Как решить проблему с циклическими зависимостями в мульти-модульном Maven проекте?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Всем привет!
Имею `Maven` проект с несколькими модулями:

```
boot

api

persistence

domain
```

Проблема следующая: модуль `boot` видит модуль `domain` без прямых зависимостей(`dependency`). В `pom` файлах специально отключил сторонние зависимости во всех модулях, оставил только родственные связи, в итоге структура всех модулей одинаковая(структура `pom` файла), но остальные 2 модуля остаются в тени. Пробовал сделать следующую цепочку зависимостей: `boot` -> `api` -> `persistence` -> `domain`. В итоге получаю гору циклический зависимостей, но если убираю `dependency` в окне просмотра зависимостей их нет.

```
pom.xml module-boot

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>pizza-api</module>
        <module>pizza-domain</module>
        <module>pizza-persistence</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pizzapool</groupId>
    <artifactId>pizza-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pizza-boot</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pizzapool</groupId>
            <artifactId>pizza-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

pom.xml module-api

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>pizza-boot</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.pizzapool</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pizza-api</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.hateoas/spring-hateoas -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pizzapool</groupId>
            <artifactId>pizza-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webflux -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>-->


    </dependencies>

</project>

pom.xml module-persistence

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>pizza-boot</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.pizzapool</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pizza-persistence</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pizzapool</groupId>
            <artifactId>pizza-domain</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

</project>

pom.xml module-domain

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>pizza-boot</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.pizzapool</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pizza-domain</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.Alpha6</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: На лицо нарушение принципа Dependency Invertion.

Comment: Почему модуль `boot` видит модуль `domain`, но не видит остальные модули? Хотя структура `pom` файла во всех модулях одинаковая.